# Collatz function not exiting correctly

Tags: python, function, recursion, collatz

Here's a program that is intended to count the length of a Collatz sequence recursively:

```
def odd_collatz ( n ):
    return (3 * n) + 1

def even_collatz ( n ):
    return int(n / 2)

def collatz_counter ( initialNumber, initialLength ):
    length = initialLength

    while True:
        if initialNumber == 1:
            return length

        elif initialNumber != 1:
            length += 1

            if initialNumber % 2 == 0:
                 collatz_counter(even_collatz(initialNumber), length)

            else:
                collatz_counter(odd_collatz(initialNumber), length)

print(collatz_counter(13, 1)
```

The expected answer should be 10. However, the program gets stuck in an infinite loop. At the second to last step of the sequence `initalNumber` equals 2. The program functions as expected: `collatz_counter` is called using `even_collatz` and the number 10.

The expected action of the next step would be to run `collatz_counter` with an `initialNumber` of 1 and an `initialLength` of 10. What I would expect would happen is that the first if statement would evaluate to true, `collatz_counter` should return `length` and then exit. This is not, however, what happens:

What actually happens is that the function evaluates the first if statement, runs the `return length` line, and then jumps to the line of code under `if initialNumber % 2...` and the whole process repeats itself over and over and over in an infinite loop.

Any ideas as to why this might be happening?

Comment: If the initial number isn't 1, the elif and else clauses don't return anything. You're also calling a function inside itself: `collatz_counter`

Comment: Please fix the code.  It looks like you are missing some closing parenthesis in the last few lines of `collatz_counter()`.  Also, as @Andrew implies, those lines should be  **`return`** `collatz_counter(...)`

Comment: I have edited it. They were typos in SE only, in the actual code they were correct. linusG gave me a heads up and I fixed them. 

Andrew, that's why I can't figure out what the problem is, it's evaluating things that shouldn't be evaluated.

Comment: Now its another typo: should be ``print(collatz_counter(13, 1))``, you've missed one closing parenthesis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mixing recursion and looping in a bit of an odd way. The problem is `while True:`. Because you never return anything from within the loop there is nothing stopping it from going on forever. Your code reaches 1 then just keeps adding to the length. Here is a fixed version.

```
def odd_collatz ( n ):
    return (3 * n) + 1

def even_collatz ( n ):
    return int(n / 2)

def collatz_counter ( initialNumber, initialLength ):
    length = initialLength


    if initialNumber == 1:
        return length

    elif initialNumber != 1:
        length += 1

        if initialNumber % 2 == 0:
            return collatz_counter(even_collatz(initialNumber), length)

        else:
            return collatz_counter(odd_collatz(initialNumber), length)

print(collatz_counter(13, 1))
```

Comment: That solved it! And I learned something about how to properly do recursion. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a typo to me. You define a function `collatz_counter` expecting two numbers.

But you call it like this:

```
...
print(collatz_counter(13), 1)
```

Just try to change the last line to:

```
print(collatz_counter(13, 1))
```

And it should be fine.

Hope this helps!

Comment: To piggy back off this, if `length` is defaulting to 0, it gets incremented to 1 before the function cams itself and the function will return because the length is now 1.

Comment: That was a typo when I typed it into here. In the program, it's written correctly. Thanks for the heads up on that! I've changed it in the OP

Answer (score 0):

The main error is the `while True:` loop, coupled with the missing returns.

```
def odd_collatz ( n ):
    return (3 * n) + 1

def even_collatz ( n ):
    return int(n / 2)

def collatz_counter(initialNumber, length):
    if initialNumber == 1:
        return length
    elif initialNumber != 1:
        length += 1
        if initialNumber % 2 == 0:
             return collatz_counter(even_collatz(initialNumber), length)
        else:
            return collatz_counter(odd_collatz(initialNumber), length)

print(collatz_counter(13, 1))
```

prints 10.